# jQuery ajax call with async false is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Here I have pasted my code, I want to return the response of $.ajax as response of function a(). But before the result comes up of ajax call, it is returning the empty f. please help on this

```
a = function()
{
        var f = '';
    $.ajax({
          url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=immaulikvora&count=1&page=1&include_entities=1&callback=?',
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {
            f = data;
          }
        });    
    return f;
};


var lid = a();

alert(lid);
```

Comment: since `return f;` is not part of success function, it is executed before the success function even, that's why you are getting empty `f`.

Comment: Yes I know, How can I achieve this exact functionality to return it after the response of ajax call comes?

Comment: Usually I would say: If you think you need to set `async: false` you are already doing something wrong essentially. Why do you need to have a return value in the first place?

Comment: I want to use api response for some of my work, and the lid variable will be assigned the api response and later on I can use that variable for my another purpose. Is there any other method? can I use anyother javascript method to call my api?

Comment: @devnull - async:false is not always wrong - what if you are already in a cancellable event?

Comment: not solution for synchronous Ajax calls ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you are using jQuery 1.8+

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Please read the fine print.

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is
>   **deprecated**;
>
> you must use the complete/success/error callbacks.

try

http://jsfiddle.net/UgrLE/

Comment: can you guide please me how I can use callbacks to return the response of AJAX call to variable lid?

Comment: Hi I checked that, Its working but can I get the response returned to lid variable. How can I assign the response to lid variable? Please advice it.

Comment: without async=false, it's almost impossible to assign the response to a variable. Instead, you should ask yourself, what would you do to the response, and pass this action as callback function.

Comment: For further reading on the theory check out futures and promises, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises

Comment: I can not see why this is an accepted answer.  The issue has nothing to do with the version.  @Murali provided a correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

Please assign the ajax to jqXHR object and reading the responseText will help you.

```
 var jqXHR=$.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=immaulikvora&count=1&page=1&include_entities=1&callback=?',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false
    });    

jqXHR.responseText // This will give you the result
```

Comment: Can I use for call PageMethods ?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you work for twitter, I would assume it is failing because "**Cross-domain requests** and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation."

Deprecated != removed and even if it did I take the deprecation is in the context of the returned jqXHR which are not being used here.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It looks like @Murali provides a work-around, but the above is important to point out for those having issue with same-domain requests.