# PhantomJs - Getting value out of page.evaluate + ajax (Synchronous Version)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phantomjs

**Problem:** Extracting data from `ajax` request inside `page.evaluate`

**Description:** I usually get variables out of `page.evaluate` by simply returning them. However, I need to make an `ajax` request within the context of a page, and then I need to process its result out of the page's context.

The code I'm trying to fix is:

```
var theOutput = page.evaluate(function () {
    return $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/captcha.php',
        data: { filename: 'C:\\wamp\\www\\images\\0.png' },
        type: 'post',
        success: function (output) {
            parsed_output = $.parseHTML(output);
            return parsed_output[4].data.trim();
        },
    });
});
console.log(theOutput);
```

The variable `parsed_output[4].data.trim()` is a string. But when I log `output` I get a `[object Object]`, with the properties `abort, always, complete, done, error, fail, getAllResponseHeaders, getResponseHeader, overrideMimeType, pipe null, progress, promise, readyState, setRequestHeader, state, statusCode, success,then`.

**Question:** How can I extract `theOutput` from `page.evaluate`?

Comment: Artjom's solutions worked for me using [jquery 1.8.0](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery-1.8.0.min.js). I'm not using an earlier version because I also need the function `$.parseHTML` (added in the version 1.8.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a blocking AJAX request, you can create a temporary variable:

```
var theOutput = page.evaluate(function () {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        ...
        success: function (output) {
            parsed_output = $.parseHTML(output);
            result = parsed_output[4].data.trim();
        },
    });
    return result;
});
console.log(theOutput);
```

You can also directly access the `responseText` from the jqXHR object:

```
var theOutput = page.evaluate(function () {
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/captcha.php',
        data: { filename: 'C:\\wamp\\www\\images\\0.png' },
        type: 'post'
    });
    parsed_output = $.parseHTML(jqXHR.responseText);
    return parsed_output[4].data.trim();
});
console.log(theOutput);
```

If you fear that `async: false` is deprecated, you can simply use the underlying XMLHttpRequest to use blocking execution:

```
var theOutput = page.evaluate(function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/captcha.php', false);
    request.send($.param({ filename: 'C:\\wamp\\www\\images\\0.png' }));

    var parsed_output = $.parseHTML(request.responseText);
    return parsed_output[4].data.trim();
});
console.log(theOutput);
```

Comment: I'm getting a `null` on both solutions. Maybe `async: false` is not working? (deprecated)

Comment: `async` cannot be deprecated, because this is a property of the underlying XMLHttpRequest object. Register to the `onError` and `onConsoleMessage` events and see if there are errors. This should work. Possibly your `parsed_output[4]` selects some broken element and or there are less than 5 elements to begin with. So that `data` is undefined.

Comment: Take a look at the answer here (about async deprecated): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930202/jquery-ajax-call-with-async-false-is-not-working

Comment: I tried some fiddles with different jQuery versions and [this script](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/8c65b3431bf537d979e6) in PhantomJS. It works as expected.

Comment: I found a way to quickly check the content of the `output` variable. You can add `page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {console.log(msg);}` outside `page.open` and use `console.log` inside `page.evaluate`. Using that, I got the content of `output`, which was a bunch of html content (as expected). However, in the console, I got `null` first, and then the html content inside `output`. Meaning that, even though `async`is set to false, somehow `result` is being output BEFORE the `success` callback function is executed.

Comment: You might want to use `onCallback` instead of `onConsoleMessage`, because it is a different object path from the page context.

Comment: I switched to `onCallback` and, using the layout of the first solution, I added the line `window.callPhantom({hello: result});` after the line `result = parsed...`. The order in the console is still the same, `null` and then `CALLBACK: {"hello":"some letters and numbers here"}`. I don't understand why `console.log(output)` is being executed before `success`. I am using jquery 2.1.3 by the way.

Comment: I added a third option for blocking execution.

Comment: I implemented exactly what is in your third solution, and I tested some different implementations, but none is working. In the case of the 3rd solution, an empty line is outputted to the console and nothing else happens. I don't know what's going on. I have all those error handling functions in the script also, and I get nothing. I really don't know what to do. I think I'll need to figure out an asynchronous solution, but I don't know how to start on that (or if it's possible). Anyway, I'd like to thank you again for helping me out so many times!

Comment: Hey Artjom I tested here with jquery 1.8.0 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery-1.8.0.min.js) and the `async:false` works, however, with the latest version it doesn't work at all, neither does the XMLHttpRequest (but It might be because it's not accessing the local file).